# Change colors in graph

Tags: python, charts, colors, plotly

For a Sentiment Analysis, I wrote the following code for a  bar chart I would like to show. Now, I would like to change the color scheme to greens, but couldn't manage.
How can I change the colors?

```
# Most frequent 20 words Rating Guests English shown in bar chart
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(reviews_english_commonwords, x='Wort', y='Häufigkeit',
             hover_data=['Wort', 'Häufigkeit'], color='Häufigkeit',
             title='20 Häufigste Wörter',
             height=400)
fig.show()
```

Picture of the graph:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting to different, more standard color?  This will help narrow down the problem between *how* you are trying to set the color and *what* color you are trying to use.

Comment: `color='Häufigkeit'`: what do you mean? Did you set such cmap? Where?

Answer (score 0):

`color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.greens` add this to px.bar call.